# Can't grab the first image link out of an array of image links

Tags: vba, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to figure out a way to fetch the images from a [webpage](https://rasamalaysia.com/grilled-honey-cajun-shrimp/) using xmlhttp requests in vba. After digging deep I could notice that I can access to those images using this attribute `data-lazy-srcset`. However, this attribute produces an array of image links. What I wish to do is capture the first image link from the array.

```
Sub GetImage()
    Const Url = "https://rasamalaysia.com/grilled-honey-cajun-shrimp/"
    Dim Http As Object, Html As HTMLDocument, oImage As Object
    
    Set Html = New HTMLDocument
    Set Http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    With Http
        .Open "Get", Url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    Set oImage = Html.querySelectorAll("p > img")
    Debug.Print oImage(0).getAttribute("data-lazy-srcset")
End Sub
```

Current output:

```
https://rasamalaysia.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/honey-cajun-grilled-shrimp3.jpg 1200w, https://rasamalaysia.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/honey-cajun-grilled-shrimp3-200x300.jpg 200w, https://rasamalaysia.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/honey-cajun-grilled-shrimp3-300x450.jpg 300w, https://rasamalaysia.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/honey-cajun-grilled-shrimp3-768x1152.jpg 768w, https://rasamalaysia.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/honey-cajun-grilled-shrimp3-1024x1536.jpg 1024w
```

Expected output (the first one):

```
https://rasamalaysia.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/honey-cajun-grilled-shrimp3.jpg
```

> How can I scrape the first image link out of an array of image links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've described the problem well and it at least looks like a simple array index problem.

Turn the string into array by splitting it on spaces and take out the first element.

Add to top of declares

```
Dim varArray as Variant
```

Then add the lines

```
' Split into an array using blank spaces as delimiter
varArray = Split(oImage(0).getAttribute("data-lazy-srcset"), " ")
' This should return your first image
Debug.Print varArray(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a more efficient and faster way. Simply select by `size-full` class, for an element where there is no need to split a string, and where you can simply extract as the appropriate image direct from an attribute:

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetImage()
    Const Url = "https://rasamalaysia.com/grilled-honey-cajun-shrimp/"
    Dim Http As Object, Html As HTMLDocument

    Set Html = New HTMLDocument
    Set Http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    With Http
        .Open "Get", Url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    Debug.Print Html.querySelector(".size-full").getAttribute("data-pin-media")

End Sub
```

Comment: This is undoubtedly better way to achieve the same.